# Псевдопростое число

Tags: c++, простые-числа

Назовем псевдопростым число, которое раскладывается в произведение двух неравных между собой простых чисел. Определите, является ли заданное натуральное число псевдопростым.
На вход программе подается натуральное число N, не понимаю  где ошибка

Пример: 10 - YES
9 - NO

```
#include <math.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

bool prost(int num)
{

    for (long long i = 2; i * i <= num; i++)
        if (num % i == 0) {
            return  false;
            break;
        }
    return true;
}


int main()
{
    int n, op, num,del=0,p;

    cin >> n;
    for (int i = 2; i < n; i++)
    {
        if ((prost(i) == true) && (n % i == 0))

            del = i;
            break;
    }
    if (prost(del)==true) cout << "YES";
    else cout << "NO";


}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Замените

```
if ((prost(i) == true) && (n % i == 0))
        del = i;
        break;
```

на

```
if ((prost(i) == true) && (n % i == 0))
{
        del = n/i;
        break;
}
```

а то вы проверяете опять первый делитель, и добавьте проверку, что `del != i` (разные простые делители).

В целом, я бы делал так...

```
bool pseudo_prime(int n)
{
    int d[3] = {0};
    int idx = 0;
    if (n < 4) return false;
    if (n%4 == 0) return false;
    if (n%2 == 0) { d[idx++] = 2; n/= 2; }
    for(int i = 3; i*i <= n; i += 2)
    {
        while(n%i == 0)
        {
            d[idx++] = i;
            n /= i;
            if (idx == 2) break;
        }
        if (idx == 2) break;
    }
    if (n > 1) d[idx++];
    if (idx != 2) return false;
    return (d[0] != d[1]);
}

int main()
{
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    cout << (pseudo_prime(n) ? "YES\n" : "NO\n");
}
```

Comment: И скобки не помешают.

Answer (score 1):

```
    if (prost(i) && (n % i == 0) && prost(n / i) && (i != n / i)) {
      cout << "YES";
      return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Верну долг :) - надо выбросить еще `if (prost(del)==true) cout << "YES"; else`.

Comment: @Harry Это точно.